# Intercept the access to a class attribute with annotations?

Tags: java, annotations

Is there any **Java annotation** enabling to intercept the access (read or write) to a *public* class attribute ?

This would enable to inject logic as you would with getters and setters, without the need of making them when it's not necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change field access to getter / setter method access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709928/change-field-access-to-getter-setter-method-access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in annotations to do this, but you could add your own.  However, Using aspect orientated programming may be what you have in mind. e.g. AspectJ

Comment: Yes I don't mind using a framework, but is there any that enables me to do what I want ?

Comment: Objectweb ASM would let you do it, but its pretty low level. You would have to check the AspectJ docs to see if it supports it.

Answer (score 1):

No. Java does not provide any means to intercept the access of an attribute. With aspect oriented programming you can achieve something like this with methods but for attributes this is impossible.

Comment: Its impossible without changing every class which access the fields. ;) If you use methods you only have to change the class which has the methods. With fields you have to change every class which uses the fields.